# flask passing json and render_template

Tags: javascript, json, flask, flask-login, flask-session

i'm a new dev , I've a Json object with data and i'm trying to pass it to a certain page using render_template

I've seen couple of answers about this but for some reason none of them have worked for me

i know the connection between Javascript and Flask is solid as i can console.log("string") at Onload function in JS but it doesn't seem to recognise anything i pass with the render template

things i have tried so far

saving json object as variable and pass it with the render template.

```
    x = {"Success": True , "Msg":" lets try to get jinja to work - email {{ current_user.email }} " , "displayname":current_user.name}
    t = "test"
    return render_template("index.html", x=x ,t=t)
```

on JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' , function () {
console.log("loaded");


const onStay = new XMLHttpRequest();
onStay.open('post' , "stay" , true);
onStay.send(null);

onStay.onload = ()=>{

console.log("i got response from flask ... onstay.onload , cheers !");
//console.log(x);
var  rt = t;
console.log(rt);
var resStay = JSON.parse(x.responseText);
var tt = JSON.parse('{{ x | tojson | safe}}');
```

so i'm also testing if i can pass jinja2 code or flask_login code actually save it in a variable of some sort and respond to it with JS

the second attempt was trying to jsonify method and parse it

on python :

```
X = jsonify({"Success": True , "Msg":" lets try to get jinja to work - 
email {{ current_user.email }} " , "displayname":current_user.name})
return render_template("index.html", X=X)
```

on JS end :

```
 onStay.onload = ()=>{
 var res = JSON.parse(reqSignup.responseText);
 console.log("res  === " , "\n" , res );
```

---

the output i get is

```
JavaScript.js:11 i got response from flask ... onstay.onload , cheers !
JavaScript.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined
    at XMLHttpRequest.onStay.onload (JavaScript.js:13)
onStay.onload @ JavaScript.js:13
load (async)


JavaScript.js:191 qwe@qwe.qwe 
 qwe
JavaScript.js:313 DATA   =  FormData {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access variables directly from JavaScript. What you need to do is to use these variables in the Flask Template using [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org) and in it, put a call to your JavaScript.

A classic example is putting a button, with an onclick=YourFunction(x). When calling the function it will pass the value it has in the variable.

You should be using the default Flask template engine which is [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org), but if you prefer a template engine I developed to facilitate this kind of thing, if [Sucuri](https://github.com/marcosstefani/sucuri).

Hope this helps.